Web app with Deeplink shows error in Chrome latest version (v128.0.6613.98) in iOS
I have a web app with deeplink to an iOS app using Dynamic links. This was working perfectly before but now with the latest version of Google Chrome browser (v128.0.6613.98) in iPhones, it is throwing an error.
The redirection to the app works perfectly when the iOS app is installed. If the iOS app is not installed, then it should open the web app, but on chrome, it shows a dialog saying "This site is trying to open another application" with two buttons to allow and disallow [Screenshot attached]. If pressed on "Allow" then it throws an error saying "Something went wrong. The application couldn't be opened.". Once the dialog is closed then it proceeds to open the web app as normal.
Note that this is the case when the app is not installed on the device. So, why is it giving this dialog to open an app in the first place?
Can I somehow disable this dialog?


